# How to return collection in reverse order

Tags: laravel

In my Conversation model I have

```
  protected $with = ['messages', 'users'];
```

How would I change the order that it returns the 'messages' to DESC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual Eloquent relationship looks something like this:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

So here’s what we should do to automatically order products by title in every query that uses this relationship:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product')->orderBy('name');
}
```

That’s it, everything is “in order” now!

Source: https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-relationships-with-automatic-orderby/

Comment: Thank you @tisuchi It's really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your controller, it will order messages in descending order

```
User::with(['messages' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}])->get();
```

for more see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)